# How can I get a list of embedded static files from a Razor Class Library?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-class-library

The title is the question really...

I have an embedded Razor Class Library which contains some CSS files, which are a bunch of Bootstrap Themes.

Since Razor Class Libraries compile their entire content into a single file, there is no `File System` as such, so `Directory.GetFiles` on the wwwroot/css directory does not work as it would in a normal Website project.

So, does anyone know how to get a list of embedded CSS files in code?

(in case relevant, [THIS SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090129/using-staticfileoptions-breaks-embedded-static-files-from-razor-class-library) is one I asked earlier in the development of this project and shows the code I am using to embed the static files in my RCL)

(Project uses .NET Core 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using a combination of these SO answers:

[How to get class library assembly reference in .NET Core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006608/how-to-get-class-library-assembly-reference-in-net-core-project)

[confused about resources and GetManifestResourceNames()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195570/confused-about-resources-and-getmanifestresourcenames/15574053)

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(NameSpaceForMyRCL.Class));
 string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

The code above gets me the complete list of embedded files which I can then filter with `Linq`